# Fetch data from zoopla.co.uk

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a function which looks at a cell in my spreadsheet and returns the Zoopla 'Z-Index' from the page `http://www.zoopla.co.uk/market/uk/`. Note the **`market`** section from within the URL is the only bit that changes for example BS8, BS6 etc. and this should be taken from a selected cell from within my spreadsheet. It should then return the Z-Index value which is the average property price for All, Detached, Semi and Terrace.

This is what I have created so far.

The code I have written is not pulling the average property figure for the post code from cell A1. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row = Range.("L:L").Row And _
   Target.Column = Range.("L:L").Column Then 
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.navigate "www.zoopla.co.uk/market/" & Range("A1/").Value
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = IE.document
    Dim sSPAN As String
    sSPAN = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("span")(1).innerText)
    sSPAN = Split(sSPAN, vbNewLine)(0)
    Range("O:O").Value = Split(sSPAN,", ")(0)
    Range("P:P").Value = Split(sSPAN,", ")(1)
End If
End Sub![Data needed][1]
```

Comment: What's the question? What specific problem are you encountering?

Comment: The code I have written is not pulling the average property figure for the post code from cell A1. Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script has some errors, I've corrected some lines, it works:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4

  Dim j
  Dim xcolElements
  Dim Doc, el, IE

  '
  ' if the content of the cell L1 changes:
  '
  If Target.Row = Range("L1").Row And _
     Target.Column = Range("L1").Column Then

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.Navigate "http://www.zoopla.co.uk/market/" & Range("A1").Value & "/"
    Do
      DoEvents
    Loop Until Not IE.Busy And IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Set Doc = IE.Document

    Set xcolElements = Doc.getElementsByClassName("zoopla")
    '
    j = 1
    For Each el In xcolElements
      Range("O" & j).Value = el.FirstChild.Data
      j = j + 1
    Next
    '
    IE.Quit
    '
  End If
  '
  ' destruct objects:
  '
  Set el = Nothing
  Set xcolElements = Nothing
  Set Doc = Nothing
  Set IE = Nothing
  '
End Sub
```

[image]

You know that VBA+IE is so powerful that you can do many things by adapting the above VBA code.

We use

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Instead of

```
Set IE = new InternetExplorer.Application
```

to avoid adding InternetExplorer.Application ActiveX references, minimizing RAM requirement
when opening a document without IE automation usage.

```
'
' to fill C12, C13, C14,...
'
j = 12
For Each el In xcolElements
  Range("C" & j).Value = el.FirstChild.Data
  j = j + 1
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with this and the attached photo! I have used your code however it is not importing the Z-Index value for the postcode from cell A1. As an example - visit www.zoopla.co.uk/market/BS6. Down the page it states the average value for Detached, Semi, Terrace and Flat, £538,059, £491,683, £386,899 and £227,765 respectively. I need these figures to populate 4 seperate cells. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: That is incredible! Thank you for time! One last thing however. To change the output location. I want it appear in cell "C12". I have changed this bit of the code but no luck...                             Range("C12" & j).Value = el.FirstChild.Data
      j = j + 1                                                            Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: ' to fill C12, C13, C14,...
    j = 12
    For Each el In xcolElements
      Range("C" & j).Value = el.FirstChild.Data
      j = j + 1
    Next

Comment: @jacouh  +1 For late binding

Comment: @jacouh Thank you for your help with the above I would really appreciated your help with the follow. Thanks in advance[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984280/fetch-data-from-a-web-page-to-excel-using-vba)

Comment: @jacouh - I believe Zoopla has changed the structure of their page. The code still returns the average value for Detached, Semi-Detached, Terrace and Flats however the "Z-Index" is not being returned. The Z-Index used to be calculated by averaging Detached, Semi-Detached, Terrace and Flats so easily calculated however that is not the case now. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.