# Fetch Data from a web page to Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web, web-scraping

I am trying to pull data from the following web page.

https://pro.calnea.com/login

User: tyronr@outlook.com

Pass: calnea1

Once logged in hoover over "Pro Services" and click "Comps Search (Photo)". I have typed a post code in and ticked a couple of properties already which should put them in the Shortlist. To access the short list go to the bottom on the page and on the right, there is a button which says "View Shortlist", click that. Now you see the selected properties and I want to pull each piece of data for each property, for example, cell A1 = Address, A2 = Last Sales Price, A3 = Last Sales Date etc all the way to Status. Then the next property on the next line so B1 = Address etc. If possible I want to get the image URL as well.

I am not sure of the best way around this as there is a log in however I am remaining logged in on the browser so I assume this isnt an issue?

Below is what I have so far but unfortunately I am having no luck and help would be MUCH appreciated! :)

```
Sub test()
Dim eRow As Long
Dim ele As Object
Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
RowCount = 1
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = "Address"
sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = "Last Sales Price"
sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = "Last Sales Date"
sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = "Property Type"

eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


With objIE
.Visible = True
.navigate "http://pro.calnea.com/client/cmp_shortlist/bs6?Require_EA=false&SearchMode=CMP"
Do While .Busy Or _
.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
Set what = .document.getElementsByName("q")
what.Item(0).Value = Address
Set Address = .document.getElementsByName("where")
Address.Item(0).Value = Last Sales Price
.document.getElementById("View Shortlist").Click
Do While .Busy Or _
.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
For Each ele In .document.all
Select Case ele.classname
Case "Result"
RowCount = RowCount + 1
Case "Title"
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
Case "Company"
sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
Case "Location"
sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
Case "Description"
sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
End Select
Next ele
End With
Macro1
Set objIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: very bad practice to post your info to login on this site, I have removed it for your benefit.

Comment: @Sorceri the fact that you mentioned you removed it,now someone can see the edit [history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19984280/revisions) not that i would use someone elses password but just saying its not totally removed.

Comment: Its removed as much as I can make it which is all I can do to help them.  no one should ever post their info to a public site. And if you wouldnt have posted the link it could have remained kind of hidden but now anyone can go look thanks to your link!

Comment: @Sorceri Hi Sorceri Thank you for your concern with regards to my log in details however I created that as a temporary account so people could log in

Answer (score 1):

I seen the link from [Fetch data from zoopla.co.uk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835394/fetch-data-from-zoopla-co-uk/19836482#19836482), I just corrected some VBA syntax error, please check this:

```
Sub sofFetchDataFromWebPage()
  Dim RowCount, eRow As Long
  Dim sht, ele As Object, what, Address
  Dim objIE

'
  Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
'
' Set sht = ActiveSheet

  RowCount = 1
  sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = "Address"
  sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = "Last Sales Price"
  sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = "Last Sales Date"
  sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = "Property Type"

  eRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

  Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  With objIE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://pro.calnea.com/client/cmp_shortlist/bs6?Require_EA=false&SearchMode=CMP"
    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
      DoEvents
    Loop
    Set what = .document.getElementsByName("q")
    what.Item(0).Value = "Address"
    Set Address = .document.getElementsByName("where")
    Address.Item(0).Value = "Last Sales Price"
    .document.getElementById("View Shortlist").Click
    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
      DoEvents
    Loop
    For Each ele In .document.all
      Select Case ele.classname
        Case "Result"
          RowCount = RowCount + 1
        Case "Title"
         sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
        Case "Company"
          sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
        Case "Location"
          sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
        Case "Description"
          sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
      End Select
    Next
  End With
  Set objIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

As you has logged in in another IE Window, you may not need do login here again.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at the code. I have high lighted the bits of information which I need to take for each property and paste on each line of Excel however the code is not working. I have only asked it to get four pieces of data as of yet and this is to keep it simple until I have figured it out, however the end result is to get all the information for each property on each Row. Any help with this would be great. Thank you  [link](http://s13.postimg.org/58f585ihj/CAlnea.png)

Comment: You shall study returned HTML document structure for see classnames, tagnames, attributes to determine the strategy to fetch data.